new-relic's browser-agent npm package can't be found
I'm following the instructions mentioned in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@newrelic/browser-agent#new-relic-browser-agent; unfortunately, when my application reaches the import statement, it fails.
import { BrowserAgent } from '@newrelic/browser-agent/loaders/browser-agent'
const options = {
    init: { distributed_tracing: { enabled: true }, privacy: { cookies_enabled: true }, ajax: { deny_list: ["bam.nr-data.net"] } },
    info: { beacon: "bam.nr-data.net", errorBeacon: "bam.nr-data.net", licenseKey: "xxx", applicationID: "xxx", sa: 1 },
    loader_config: { accountID: "xxx", trustKey: "xxx", agentID: "xx", licenseKey: "xx", applicationID: "xx" }
}

new BrowserAgent(options)

The exception I receive is

./src/App.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@newrelic/browser-agent/loaders/browser-agent' in '~/code/clients/web/ClientApp/src'

I assumed it's because project isn't set up for using @ references, would have to update tsconfig.json; so I added the following to the tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
    }
  }
}

packages.json
"scripts": {
    "prepare": "cd ../.. && husky install Sontiq.Unified.Web/ClientApp/.husky",
    "build-css": "cross-env PUBLIC_URL=/app sass src/Assets/css:public/css --style=compressed --no-source-map",
    "watch-css": "cross-env PUBLIC_URL=/app npm run build-css && sass src/Assets/css:public/css --watch --update --style=compressed --no-source-map",
    "start": "rimraf ./build && npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "cross-env PUBLIC_URL=/app npm run build-css && cross-env PUBLIC_URL=/app DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts build",
    "start-js": "cross-env PUBLIC_URL=/app DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts start",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },


Do you mean the actual file content changes? What even is your start script? Give a [mre].

@jonrsharpe yes. the changes in the tsconfig.json file for path are all gone when I run npm start from command line.

Go to Package.json and show us what is in your start script

@white-wolf97 updated the question.

@AliKhakpouri I'm having the same issue. Have you made any progress regarding the matter?
